# Parallel RLC bandpass filter Bandwidth incorrect

Tags: filter, passive-networks, band-pass

I have been trying to create a bandpass filter with the cut-off frequency at \$\mathrm{200Hz}\$ and \$\mathrm{4800Hz}\$ I have managed to get the centre frequency to \$\mathrm{2500Hz}\$. The bandwidth on the to be non-existent and I have somehow created a really bad high-pass filter.

Below is the circuit I have created:
[image]

I am using a \$\mathrm{40nF}\$ capacitor, \$\mathrm{0.1H}\$ and a \$\mathrm{1718}\Omega\$ resistor in parallel which is all in series with another \$\mathrm{1718\Omega}\$ resistor.

This then creates the AC sweep:
[image]

In order to get the values I have I did the following:

I knew that resonant frequency is 
$$
f_o= \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}
$$

I assigned a value to \$L\$ of \$\mathrm{0.1H}\$ and rearranged to get the capacitance

Then for bandwidth:
$$
B = R\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}
$$
I knew the values of \$C\$, \$L\$ and the bandwidth (\$\mathrm{2600Hz}\$)

*I realise now that the values of the resistors are incorrect but I have also tried \$\mathrm{1450}\Omega\$ resistors and the same issue

Can anyone please explain to me why this has happened and how to fix it?

Comment: What method and calculations have you use to get to the current schematic? Note that you can **not** cascade "individual" calculated  filters.

Comment: Try the bandpass filter designs and plotting tools here.  http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Fkeisan.htm

Comment: Given the  Q is much less than one, this is not a standard LC bandpass design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have managed to get the centre frequency to 2500 Hz

If you want equal amplitude cut-off frequencies of 200 Hz and 4800 Hz, the centre frequency you need is 980 Hz. This is calculated as \$\sqrt{200\times 4800}\$ = 979.8 Hz.

That is the centre frequency you need to aim for.

Also, when you are so asymmetrical with your 3 dB frequencies (relative to Fc) the bandwidth formula you used becomes inappropriate because it relies on both 3 dB points being close to each other. You would probably fair better with a double RC filter given the gulf between 200 Hz and 4800 Hz.

Comment: I see that is a very good point with respect to the large difference between the cut-off frequencies. Please, could you provide a link to how you determined the centre frequency?

Comment: @Andy aka...I think, the relations between Q, B and Fo for such a filter are always valid - independent on the width of the passband. Hence, it does not matter if the 3dB frequencies are close to each other - or not. Such a bandpass is always "unsymmetric" with respect to the center frequency.,

Comment: @sam lemonts...The square root formula mentioned by Andy aka applies to ALL second-order bandpass functions. The center frequency is always the geometric mean of the two edge frequencies.

Comment: This link shows you how the formula can be derived (see my detailed answer): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234752/why-is-center-frequency-of-a-bandpass-filter-is-given-by-the-geometric-average-o/234768